# Is stride as an image parameter present in an image file stored in a disc?

Tags: c, file, image-processing, png, stride

I am working with 100×125 size emoji images. To test that our algo works correctly for images with different parameters, I was asked to modify the stride of an image. E.g. "generate test data files where the stride is set to 132 and see if the algo works for this data".

There are plenty of tools that can modify the width/height of an image file, but I can't find a software that modifies the stride.

The way I understand the stride is that if the image has a width W of 125 pixels, a height H of 100 pixels, then its stride S could be 128 pixels and it can be stored in the RAM memory as an array of `S * H * sizeof(padded pixel)` bytes.

**What happens to the stride when the image is saved as a file to the disc**? Lets take a PNG format as an example.

Is the stride as a parameter together with the extra S-W pixels per row also stored in the file? Or is a stride merely an implementation detail of the library that reads an image file into the RAM memory?

Comment: PNG is an open format, the specification is available for anyone to read.

Comment: Stride is dependent on image format and other considerations such as memory layout for specific performance reasons.  In general it can be derived from the pixel format and image width, and there's no need to actually store it.  But again, that depends.  A better question would be: why are you asking?

Comment: @paddy I edited the question to explain the reason for asking.

Comment: IMHO, the stride is not relevant on disk as it describes the offset (normally in bytes) between successive scanlines of pixels (normally) in memory. Software is at liberty to read pixels into memory with any stride it chooses.

Answer (score 3):

Stride is a description, in part, of how an image is laid out in memory. It specifies the distance between certain elements.

Take your example of an image with 100 rows and 125 columns. Let’s suppose each pixel is four bytes, in some type named `Pixel`. We could store this image in an array declared `Pixel A[100][125]`. Then the stride between elements in a row would be four bytes, and the stride between elements in a column would be 125•4 byte = 500 bytes.

We would also store this image in an array declared `Pixel B[100][128]`. The extra three elements in each row would be wasted, but the array with these dimensions perhaps could be aligned for easier use with certain hardware features. In this array, the stride between elements in a row is still four bytes, but the stride between elements in a column is 128•4 bytes = 512 bytes.

Another option could be we store this image in an array declared `Pixel C[100][125][4]`, where all the pixels of this image are in `C[i][j][0]`, and three other images have their pixels stored in `C[i][j][1]`, `C[i][j][2]`, and `C[i][j][3]`. This interspersed storage of the image might facilitate some parallel processing. In this array, the stride between elements in a row is 4•4 bytes = 16 bytes, and the stride between elements in a column is 125•4•4 bytes = 2000 bytes.

In summary, the stride(s) tell us where in memory the array elements are. If the stride between elements in a column is *x* and the stride between elements in a row is *y*, then element *i*, *j* is located at the base of the array plus *i*•*x* + *j*•*y*.

To change a stride of an image, you must rearrange the data in memory.

(Also note that some people might refer to a stride as just a number, such as “a stride of two.” This is sloppy terminology; measurements should always include units, so a stride might be two elements or eight bytes. Sometimes the unit is implied in context, but an author should make it clear.)